# Cannot SSH from outside LAN despite port forwarding seems fine

Tags: networking, server, ssh, lan, sshd

Running Ubuntu 12.04, I've set up the OpenSSH server. I can connect from within LAN, but not from outside. I am using the same `sshd_config` file as on my other Ubuntu 12.04 machines (that sit in a different LAN).

> $ ssh 192.168.0.2

works fine, but

> $ ssh 65.76.97.222

(made up IP address) does not work. Nothing happens. No error message, or anything. The prompt just sits there.

Thanks to comments below, I have managed to verify via websites [canyouseeme.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) and [ShieldsUP](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup) that port 22 is indeed open.

Using the option `-vvv`, I get the following:

```
$ ssh -vvv 65.76.97.222
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 65.76.97.222 [65.76.97.222] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
```

And then the prompt just sits there.

Further debug information from `var/log/auth.log`:

```
$ grep sshd /var/log/auth.log
[cutting old lines...]    
Jul  6 10:23:05 mymachine sshd[7871]: Did not receive identification string from 65.76.97.222
```

I am allowing any user to connect, in particular my own username. What confuses me is that I have not had this problem on any other machine, although they are on a different lan. This lan has only one computer attached to it. Any ideas of how to proceed from here?

Comment: try using the verbose option (`-v`, `-vv`, to `-vvv`) to get extra info re: the connection. e.g., `ssh -vvv -p 51555 65.76.97.222`.

Comment: check the forwarding port http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to reflect your comments.

Comment: When this happened to me, the configuration of my router was wrong. I forwarded external port 22 to the port 22 of my device, but using the UDP protocol instead of TCP.

Answer (score 6):

Check your gateway on the SSH server is set to the router doing the port-forwarding.

`route -n`

The default route should point back to that router, otherwise, you will be able to initiate connections through it, but the ACK's won't go anywhere!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things for you to check.

1. Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure that you don't have any funny `AllowUsers` entries.
2. Specify the user that you want to connect as:

   ```
   ssh USER@SERVER
   ssh SERVER -lUSER
   ```
3. Check your firewall (`iptables`):

   ```
   sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
   sudo iptables -L -t nat --line-numbers
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Need to check that port forwarding is working correctly i usually check by going to https://www.grc.com/shieldsup > Proceed > put your port number in the box and click user specified custom port probe. That should tell you if that TCP port is in fact open to public

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question to reflect your suggestion. Problem remains however.

Comment: HUH well the network is ruled out so looks like a config issue. Try `grep sshd /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: The following line is then added to `auth.log`: `Jul  6 10:23:05 mymachine sshd[7871]: Did not receive identification string from 65.76.97.222`

Answer (score 1):

Are you declaring a user?

`ssh Jimmy@65.76.97.222 -p51555`

If you gave the code the way you are using it then I believe that it will default to the current user name.

Furthermore, you need to have a user on the TARGET system with permission. in the above example "Jimmy"

Comment: I have indeed. I am only connecting with the same user all the time, and further, `sshd_config` allows any user to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in from a computer that is not on the network. I used an SSH app on my smartphone. At first, it didn't work but then I turned off the wifi and it worked as expected.  I had the same issue with my webserver.

The issue has to do with NAT loopback.

Many routers and some security tools prevent loopback connections as a security feature. This means that a machine on your local network cannot connect to the external IP address (such as 208.112.93.73) of a machine that is also on your local network. Connecting to a local IP address (such as 192.168.0.2) of that same machine works fine.

Check if your router has an "enable NAT loopback" feature.